# Keeping a user's passwords, but can't hash them

Tags: storage, credentials

I'm making a web application to provide intermediary service for customers to facilitate their interaction with a set of other web applications.

A simplified example would be to let a user access his emails from my site. For this I will need his email and his email's password. To prevent the user from needing to retype his password every time, I would like to store this. Of course, customers would not feel safe if I was storing their passwords in plain text. But I can't store it as a hash, as I need to resubmit this password every time the user uses my service.

I thought about storing his password on his computer, and getting the web page to send it to me. I don't think that would make them feel safer though.

An alternative I thought of would be to store these passwords in plain text in a separate, individual database for each user, that only that particular user has permission to read after he has logged on to my website using his credentials for my service. Again, I don't feel right storing his password like this but if the permissions are set right, only one customers details can be compromised (if his log ins for my site are compromised).

I would like suggestions about the safest way to approach this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an interesting point in your question:

> I thought about storing his password on his computer, and getting the web page to send it to me. I don't think that would make them feel safer though.

Do you want the users to **be** safe, or to **feel** safe ? That's not the same thing.

If you store the password on your server, you become responsible for it. There are some tricks which can be used to reduce the risks of leakage, but risks will still exist. For instance, if you store the emails in encrypted form in the database, then the server software will have to decrypt them before usage, so the server must know the decryption key, but that key needs not be known *to the database*; it could be stored in a file, and decryption done on the server (*not* with SQL-based cryptographic abilities offered by the database). This may provide some protection against SQL injection attacks. It is a delicate dance: if the server can access the stored passwords *alone*, then dumping the *whole server contents* (e.g. a complete hard disk image) must grant access as well; any encryption key must be there. Encryption, in that case, is a bet on the idea that attacks will be *partial*: an attacker will dump the database contents, not the whole disk.

A better system may look like this:

- For each user *u*, a random symmetric key *K<sub>u</sub>* is generated.
- The email password for user *u* is encrypted with *K<sub>u</sub>*; that's what is stored on the server.
- *K<sub>u</sub>* is NOT stored on the server, but on the client.
- Upon connection, *K<sub>u</sub>* is sent from the client to the server. The server uses it to recover the email password, in RAM only; the decrypted password, and *K<sub>u</sub>*, are never written to files or database.

Storage of a client-specific secret value on the client, sent back to the server: that's a HTTP cookie. Be sure to mark it [Secure and HttpOnly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly), and to use HTTPS for all the connections.

With that system:

- The emailing password is not stored on the client system, and thus won't be put at risk when the user's smartphone is stolen.
- The server's permanent storage (files, database) does not allow password recovery. An attacker who steals the whole system (he grabs the machines and makes a run for it) will not be able to obtain the passwords, regardless of how much computing power he dedicates to the tasks (assuming that the encryption was done properly, of course)(this contrasts with password hashing, where weak passwords can still be cracked, at a cost).

However:

- If your server is hijacked "silently", then the attacker will be able to observe the passwords when put to use. This is unavoidable in your system. The only way to avoid that would be a ticketing system à la [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29), used by the *email server* and the *client system*, your server being a simple relay for the Kerberos ticket; but normal email server don't do Kerberos, and neither do client systems (in particular when the "client" is some Javascript in a Web page).
- If the user loses his cookies (e.g. he switches from his phone to his desktop computer, and has no syncing system between the two), then *K<sub>u</sub>* is lost and the user must re-enter his email password.

The latter point is, again, inherent. If your server does not store enough data to recover the email password without the user's help, then... the server *cannot* recover the email password without the user's help. If the user is also helpless, then the data is lost.